# Is there a function $f$ such that $f(.7x+.3y)=.5f(x)+.5f(y)$ for all $0\le x\le y\le 1$?

Tags: functions

Find a function $f$ such that $f(0.7x+0.3y)=0.5f(x)+0.5f(y)$ for all $0\le x\le y\le 1$?

I know that a piecewise linear function can satisfy the requirement for some $x\le y$, but not all.

Comment: a constant function obviously works

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Differentiate both sides with respect to one of the variables.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!